# Why is struct in C working even with less memory allocation?

Tags: c, struct

Malloc function in C allocates the size of memory passed into it's argument in bytes.
Here my struct variable has two integer values.So size of struct should be 8 bytes. I am only allocating 1 bytes and it's still working.

Why?

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
    int a;
    int b;
}ab; 
int main(){

    struct node * nl=(struct node *)malloc(1); //I am allocating memory here
    nl->b=89;
    nl->a=45;
    printf("%d %d %ld",nl->a,nl->b,sizeof(int));
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7bCoJAEIbv9ykGI9gNTYKCYtP7HmNP6sIeYl0vSnp20w0kh2GY/5ujKFohpmmnnTCDVHDvo9T@2NVog4zmC@tjGEQE56UaEcymXQRG15RT9GGcAlqEZdphMqJU/ZuEAzhT4Q0hlhnjBT4RCmX5AGYhARa1a8Eq68MLOhVUWuZMUfPqeqOrYtX58lPPMN9ucLaXsLiRWZ4aUuR5r9/KN3juIWR@dpq@)

Comment: Google "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write past the end of allocated memory, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which means you can't reliably predict what the program will do.  It could crash, it could output strange results, or (as in this case) it can appear to work properly.

How undefined behavior manifests itself can change by making a seemingly unrelated change, such as adding an unused local variable or adding a call to `printf` for debugging.  It could also change by compiling with different optimization settings or with a different compiler.

Just because the program *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

Answer (score 0):

On most architectures, memory is allocated in 4k "pages" and no smaller. Malloc is placing your single requested byte somewhere in either one of these pages or just beyond the program break.

As long as you don't write beyond the allocated page, the virtual memory system is unaware of your transgression and won't segfault you. Of course, there's no way of knowing if or when an *illegal* access will happen, and thus in the C standard this behavior is undefined.